# Make an argument of type BTreeMap optional

Tags: rust

Say, I have a function which accepts `BTreeMap` as an argument and I want to make it optional. What's the better way to indicate that:

- leave it as it is (`BTreeMap`) and pass an instance of `BTreeMap` with no key and values
- make it `Option<BTreeMap>`

Answer (score 2):

Your question is highly abstract and really can’t be answered without reference to a concrete example. A lot depends on the desired semantics, frankly.

Some questions you may wish to consider:

- Does it make sense to be passing it an empty BTreeMap?
- Is the behaviour consistent between an empty and a full BTreeMap?
- If it’s made an Option, what happens if Some empty BTreeMap is passed?

Based on these questions and others like them, you must decide what is most appropriate for your specific example.

Another option that may be relevant is providing different functions.

Comment: 1), 2), 3) - it can be if I handle those cases in the code.